# How to read a binary file of type complex64 values in Python

Tags: python

I have a binary file that contains several complex numbers of type `complex64`? (i.e. four bytes of type float for the real part and another four bytes for the imaginary part). The real and imaginary parts are multiplexed so that the real part is stored first and followed by the imaginary part.

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you have?

Comment: complex64 is a complex number represented by two 32-bit floats (real and imaginary components). Is it what you have in your file?

Comment: @Moses, I don't know if there is a way to upload here, but the complex values in the file have been written from a program called GNURadio, and the docs say that a binary file of complex numbers stores the real and imag parts as 32-bits floats (first element is the real and the second is the imag) I tried to read the file using the following command but I could not get the numbers that I was expecting: `numpy.fromfile('file_name', dtype=complex)`
@Jacques, yes this is what I have. I was expecting `[0, 2+j, -3.14-7.99j]` but I get something like: `[0 +7.81e-3j, -1.29e+5 +0j, 7.8e-3 -1.29e+5j]`

Comment: The doc is here:http://www.nutaq.com/blog/gnu-radio-file-source-and-sink. Why don't you do `numpy.fromfile('file_name', dtype=numpy.complex64)`?

Comment: http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/FAQ#What-is-the-file-format-of-a-file_sink-How-can-I-read-files-produced-by-a-file-sink seems to indicate the same use as my comment above

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the error you encounter by creating an array of `complex64` from `[0, 2+j, -3.14-7.99j]`, saving it to a file and reading it as Python built-in `complex` type.

The issue is that the built-in `complex` type has the size of a C `double` which, depending on your plateform, may differ from 32-bits (256 bits on my machine).

You must use `numpy.fromfile('file_name', dtype=numpy.complex64)` to read your file correctly, i.e. make sure the complex numbers are read as two 32-bits floating point numbers.